# Why C program compiled in Xcode has strange memory layout?

Tags: c, xcode, memory-layout

I have the following C code:

```c
// test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  printf("location of code    : %p\n", (void *)main);
  void *heap = malloc(1);
  printf("location of heap    : %p\n", heap);
  int stack = 3;
  printf("location of stack   : %p\n", (void *)&stack);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile this code via `gcc` and `clang`:

```sh
gcc test.c -o test1
clang test.c -o test2
```

Both program runs as expected, outputing somthing like:

```
location of code    : 0x101b95ec0
location of heap    : 0x7fecde5041c0
location of stack   : 0x7ffeee06a6b8
```

Which indicates that, the heap's starting position is closer to stack rather than code.

However, if I use Xcode GUI to compile this code, and the output is something like:

```
location of code    : 0x100000ec0
location of heap    : 0x100610b10
location of stack   : 0x7ffeefbff70c
```

I know that Xcode uses `clang` as compiler, but the output is confusing. Does Xcode do something to restrict heap size, or something else?

Comment: `&stack` is not the start of the stack, it is address of a local variable in the main function's stack frame. That could be anywhere depending on command line arguments, environment variables and many other factors. Then there are the optimization, debug flags, libraries linked etc. What is the point of this comparison?

Comment: Also Address Space Layout Randomization!

Comment: It's almost certainly not a consequence of *compiling* in Xcode, but of *running* it from Xcode. By default, Xcode runs programs under a debugger and that deliberately changes certain behaviors. Try changing the scheme settings to turn off the debugger and all other diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

Modify it with function call seems the same issue.  But increase the heap size to much larger (10000000000 then 100000000000 one more zero), you may note the change from 0xf... back to 0x1... still strange.

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#define HEAPSIZE 10000000000 // 100000000000 one more zero trigger 0x1 to 0x7


// https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62906466/why-c-program-compiled-in-xcode-has-strange-memory-layout


//1
int global; /* Uninitialized variable stored in bss*/
int global2 = 10; 

void test1(int stack);

void test1(int stack){
    stack = 4;
    printf("location of stack      - %p and %d\n", (void *)&stack, stack);

}

void test2(int *stack);

void test2(int *stack){
    * stack = 4;
    printf("location of stack      - %p and %d\n", (void *)stack, *stack);

}

int main(void) 
{ 
    //2 
    static int i; /* Uninitialized static variable stored in bss */
    //3a
    static int j = 100; /* Initialized static variable stored in DS*/

    printf("location of global2    : %p\n", (void *)&global2);
    
    printf("location of static j   : %p\n", (void *)&j);
    
    printf("location of code       : %p\n", (void *)main);
    void *heap = malloc(HEAPSIZE * sizeof(int)); // malloc(1);
    printf("location of heap       : %p\n", heap);
    printf("location of heap end   : %p\n", heap + HEAPSIZE - 1);
    int var = 3;
    printf("location of var        : %p and %d\n", (void *)&var, var);

    test1(var);
    printf("location of test1(var) : %p and %d\n", (void *)&var, var);

    test2(&var);
    printf("location of test2(var) : %p and %d\n", (void *)&var, var);


    return 0; 

    // check size -xml M
}
```

10000000000 case

```
location of global2    : 0x10ea54018
location of static j   : 0x10ea5401c
location of code       : 0x10ea52d40
location of heap       : 0x7fa29ac00000
location of heap end   : 0x7fa4eecbe3ff
location of var        : 0x7ffee11ada7c and 3
location of stack      - 0x7ffee11ada3c and 4
location of test1(var) : 0x7ffee11ada7c and 3
location of stack      - 0x7ffee11ada7c and 4
location of test2(var) : 0x7ffee11ada7c and 4
```

100000000000 case (one more zero)

```
location of global2    : 0x10cf8e018
location of static j   : 0x10cf8e01c
location of code       : 0x10cf8cd40
location of heap       : 0x115b3a000
location of heap end   : 0x185e2a87ff
location of var        : 0x7ffee2c73a7c and 3
location of stack      - 0x7ffee2c73a3c and 4
location of test1(var) : 0x7ffee2c73a7c and 3
location of stack      - 0x7ffee2c73a7c and 4
location of test2(var) : 0x7ffee2c73a7c and 4
```

You may note that the function variable (the one not using pointer) is still 0x7ff...

try clang the behaviour is the same change.

But the change in additional 0 does not trigger any change in Xcode and always 0x1....

try in under docker ubuntu 20 under Mac
and the trigger point is #define HEAPSIZE 10000
// 10000 0x5 // 100000 0x7

Very confusing.

```
root@4519bf65652d:/src/testxcode.c2# make m
cc -g -o M m.c 
root@4519bf65652d:/src/testxcode.c2# make mr
size -x ./M
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  0x9e9   0x270    0x10    3177     c69 ./M
size ./M
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   2537     624      16    3177     c69 ./M
./M
location of global2    : 0x5577dac6d010
location of static j   : 0x5577dac6d014
location of code       : 0x5577dac6a1f8
location of heap       : 0x7fa282247010
location of heap end   : 0x7fa28225f6af
location of var        : 0x7ffd1a9826dc and 3
location of stack      - 0x7ffd1a9826bc and 4
location of test1(var) : 0x7ffd1a9826dc and 3
location of stack      - 0x7ffd1a9826dc and 4
location of test2(var) : 0x7ffd1a9826dc and 4
root@4519bf65652d:/src/testxcode.c2# make m 
cc -g -o M m.c 
root@4519bf65652d:/src/testxcode.c2# make mr
size -x ./M
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  0x9e9   0x270    0x10    3177     c69 ./M
size ./M
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   2537     624      16    3177     c69 ./M
./M
location of global2    : 0x56297cec6010
location of static j   : 0x56297cec6014
location of code       : 0x56297cec31f8
location of heap       : 0x56297d9516b0
location of heap end   : 0x56297d953dbf
location of var        : 0x7ffe0bbaac8c and 3
location of stack      - 0x7ffe0bbaac6c and 4
location of test1(var) : 0x7ffe0bbaac8c and 3
location of stack      - 0x7ffe0bbaac8c and 4
location of test2(var) : 0x7ffe0bbaac8c and 4
root@4519bf65652d:/src/testxcode.c2#
```